# Autostart postgresql 9.6.2 on 16.10

Tags: 16.10, postgresql, autostart

Fresh 16.10 install with fresh Postgresql-9.6.2. I can run "sudo service postgresql-9.6 start" to start postgresql service but can't get it to start on boot.

"sudo systemctl enable postgresql-9.6" returns
postgresql-9.6.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable postgresql-9.6
update-rc.d: error: postgresql-9.6 Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.

These don't return any errors but also don't make it start automatically
sudo update-rc.d postgresql-9.6 defaults
sudo update-rc.d postgresql-9.6 enable

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.6`:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
### END INIT INFO
```

and run `sudo systemctl enable postgresql-9.6` again.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.